# Django dose not validate form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have form with the name of CommentForm when the form is validated it has to return HttpResponse which is saying that the form is valid if does nothing

```
views.py
def comment(request,pk):
blog = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
comment = CommentForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse('this is request method')
context = {
    'blog':blog,
    'comment':comment,
}

return render(request, 'blog/comment.html', context)

froms.py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__'

models.py
class Comment(models.Model):

blog = models.ForeignKey('BlogPost', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
text = models.TextField()

template
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{blog.title}}
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{comment.text}}
<input type="submit">
<form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please put your code as text instead of links.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: Did you understand what is the problom

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there an error, or unexpected behavior, or what?

Comment: as you can see that in my views.py file after validating the form it has to return httpresponse but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I used class meta in my forms.py I removed class meta and I save comments to model while instantiating it in view.py.

form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
 text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

view.py

```
def comment(request,pk):
blog = BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk)
form = CommentForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comments = Comment(
            text = form.cleaned_data['text'],
            blog =blog
            )
        comments.save()
        return redirect('/blog')
else:
    context = {'blog':blog,
    'form':form}

    return render(request, 'blog/comment.html', context)
```